# Proibir de outros sites usar o meu conteúdo

Tags: php, javascript, htaccess

Olá, eu estou tentando desenvolver um código htaccess que impeça de outros sites usar o meu conteúdo. Tentei esse, mas sem sucesso, se eu digito no navegador determinado arquivo/link ele fica inativo até para mim, sendo que era pra ficar pra outra pessoa/site e no meu site ficar acessível normalmente.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?meusite\.com\.br/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /imagens/proibido.jpg [L]
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: não entendi vc quer proibir o usuário de acessar determinada url ? ou  você que proibero usuário de copiar/fazer embed da sua pagina ?

Comment: Eu quero fazer com que eu use por exemplo: meusite.com/video.mp4 em meu site, e se outra pessoa tentar acessar ele pra colocar em seu site, não vai ter como, resumindo, todo o conteúdo do meu site só iria ser reproduzido para meu site e não para terceiros, como por exemplo pegar o link e colocar dentro de um iframe

Comment: você utiliza cpanel ?

Comment: Sim, utilizo cpanel

Comment: Isso não irá funcionar mesmo que o *código* "funcione", os sites ainda podem usar o seu conteúdo. Se eles não usarem o `crossorigin` no `img` e usarem o `referer-policy: no-referrer` (`same-origin`), isso irá fazer o navegador não informar o `referer`. :D

Comment: Eu tenho essa dúvida, porque eu vejo em site que tem links com finais .m3u8, que se eu usar eles em meu site, não reproduz, é tipo uma especie de proteção de domínio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom O que você procura chama HotLink que é uma forma de  proibir as pessoas de fazerem  usu de seus arquivos assim gerando uso de bandwidth  você pode usar um codigo parecido como  esse

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp4|)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Caso não dê ative-o pelo cpanel (como você utilza cpanel)
em [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui você pode ler um rtigo sobre o  assunto 
[Hotlink o que é, e  como se proteger](https://mindnet.com.br/painel/index.php?rp=/knowledgebase/4/Hotlink-o-que-e-e-como-se-proteger.html)

[Pode gerar o seu .htaccess personalizado aqui](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/)